IIS 10: renewal CSR invalid?
When I use "Create a renewal certificate request" in IIS 10 (to try and renew an existing and expired certificate issued by Sectigo), the external CA (Sectigo) says that the resultant CSR is invalid. (The IIS exports a renewal CSR into a 7KB text file that looks like a CSR, I then copy-paste the contents into a Sectigo online form. A previous "fresh" CSR from a year ago - no issues.)
-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
*********
<snip>
/****/***********/****************+/
***********
-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----


The CSR is also larger - 7KB vs. 2KB for a previous CSR for a new cert, and several online validators also flag it as invalid (but don't say what's wrong).
What am I doing wrong? If I need to just generate a new CSR as if for a new cert instead of going through the renewal process in IIS - could anyone say why? What is the renewal process for in IIS, and why does it generate a CSR that's deemed invalid by external CAs?
P.S. A helpful soul on SE said the "cause is well known" in a comment and sent me to "IIS SSL Certificate Renewal Pain", however the "cause" is not listed there, only that the issue exists:

While I’m not sure exactly what the problem is, it simply looks like IIS is respecting none of your original certificate bit size choices and is generating a huge certificate request that is 3 times the size of a ‘normal’ certificate request. The end result is (and I’ve done this at least twice now) is that the certificate processor is likely to fail processing those renewals.

... which brings me to the title question: what does IIS "renewal" do and why are IIS renewal CSRs deemed invalid by CAs?
Thanks!

The question is largely a duplicate of How can I verify/read an IIS7 SSL renewal CSR with OpenSSL and the answer boils down to: it's flagged as invalid by most CAs because they don't know - or don't bother to figure out - how to read it.
Per this awesome answer by Jim Cheetham:

The structure of this IIS7 renewal request is actually quite elegant. It seems to start from the premise that because this is a request to renew a current certificate, it needs to prove that the request is coming from the correct host -- i.e. the host that is actually using the current certificate & ∴ owns the associated private key. In the Internet world, you prove that you are allowed to request renewals for a certificate by authenticating to your CA as the original user, rather than creating a signed CSR.

Which, to me, means the following even if it doesn't spell it out:

The CSR is valid
CAs don't accept it likely because they don't know how (or aren't equipped) to read and process it
To work around the issue:

follow instructions in Jim's answer to export a simpler version of the CSR acceptable to most CAs
create a new certificate request in IIS
re-use the existing (previous, original) CSR used in the original certificate issuance.



